# Resolving python package dependencies

Tags: python-2.7, pipenv, pep8, pipfile

I am trying to lock the Pipfile and running into below error:

```
$pipenv install
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You 
likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original 
command again.
Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ 
pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pep8 (from -r 
/var/folders/k_/z7wqjx090x7ccf11mkbpbnw80000gn/T/pipenv7upqst3zrequirements/pipenv-DczZI5- 
constraints.txt (line 2))
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Tried running suggested commands but still the same.

```
pipenv lock --clear
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You 
likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original 
command again.
Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ 
pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pep8 (from -r 
/var/folders/k_/z7wqjx090x7ccf11mkbpbnw80000gn/T/pipenv0s9lv_igrequirements/pipenv-G4Zdsv- 
constraints.txt (line 2))
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Comment: pipenv install --skip-lock however works.But then how do I generate the Pipfile.lock?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out using pipenv --support.
Turned out pipenv was using python3. So had to explicitly point it to python2 using command below and that did create Pipfile.lock

```
pipenv --two install
```